# jquery .map function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to read checkbox values using jquery .map like below:

```
var cars=$("#carsid input[name=car]:checked").map(function(){

return $(this).val();)).get().join(',');
```

But above code throwing length is null or not an object.I dont understand,what is the  issue here.Can anyone give hints?

Regards,

Raj

Answer (score 1):

Your script contains some syntax errors.  Additionally, you want to do the `.get().join(',')` on the whole object when it is returned, not on each individual element.  Try changing it to this:

```
var cars = $("#carsid input[name=car]:checked").map(function() {   
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join(',');
```

My change is to remove the extra `;))` after `$(this).val()`.  Then I moved `.get().join(',')` to operate on the returned jQuery object, rather than each element.

[Here is a demo showing this in action ->](http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/C8RLD/)

Comment: it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

you're selecting on `carsid`, which isn't a tag. You probably want a `#` before it if it's an ID, or a `.` if it's a class.